# Line feature reshape tool reshapes unselected lines

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I have QGIS 2.18.18 installed in my PC. I need to reshape large number of roads/tracks to match with Imagery. QGIS Reshape tool reshapes roads that are not even selected. Any suggestion?

Below are the screenshots for your reference

[image]

After making selection I modified the road using reshape tool

[image]

As a result, tool reshaped unselected adjacent road

[image]

Comment: It looks like the reshape tool isn't limited to selected features. The adjacent road was reshaped because you crossed it with the reshape tool. The solution would be to avoid crossing over other features when reshaping.

Comment: It does seem like the reshape tool *should* be limited to selected features, though. Normally I would suggest making a bug report/feature request, but I don't think 2.18 is being updated anymore. Maybe this issue is fixed in QGIS 3.0. Try it out and submit a bug report if not.

Comment: @csk Yeah definitely I will submit a bug report for Qgis 3.0. They have released many versions, still these kind of simple issues are there in Qgis...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is use [Node tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#node-tool) to modify existing roads. It enables you to shift the nodes, insert nodes and delete nodes.

[image]

Comment: Typically, It is the most time consuming process, when you want to edit a long road in a highway network.

Comment: That is right but in same time it is more accurate and you have more control over the line shape. But did the node tool solve your issue?

Comment: Its an alternate way to modify a line segment, but it is not the solution what I am looking for.. Because I have plenty of roads which need to be reshaped to its entire length. If I want to reshape few places in some roads, then your solution would be perfect.