# Reshape Tool issue in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I know that my question is similar to this one "[QGIS Line feature reshape issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278002/qgis-line-feature-reshape-issue)" but I'm using QGIS 3.0 and the issue is still actual.

When I reshape (add a missing part) of a line (1) it reshapes the other one as well (2) but I've selected to reshape only "left" one.

[image]

Does anyone know if it will be fixed in the near future?

Comment: Please note that it is not helpful for the discoverability of good answers to duplicate questions every couple of years. You can [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw attention to the original question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @underdark well, as you see in the previous question, there was no answer but alternative way. Previous user and I were asking for the solution not how to avoid the issue. 

The difference of my question is that previous question was about 2.xx and my is about 3.0.

Comment: Underdark is correct, this isn't a new question. When you want an update on the status of a known issue, go to the QGIS issue tracker. Here's the link for this bug report: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15149. It's still unresolved, with no ETA on a fix.